# Bootstrap Modal select dropdown expanding outside window

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have a select dropdown which is expanding outside the modal window.  Is it a better design to increase the window height and keep the dropdown inside it ? ( in which case how to do it ?)
or better keep using this current design ?

[image: dropdown over modal window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your CoffeeScript you can grab the click event of your dropdown, and reset the height of your modal window:

```
toggleModalHeight = ->
    $('#your_drop_down').on 'click', (event) ->
        $('#modal_id').css('height','new height here')


$(document).ready toggleModalHeight
#For avoid Turbolinks issues
$(document).on 'page:load', toggleModalHeight
```

Within the `toggleModalHeight` function you can even calculate the new height of your modal and set it properly. Hope have helped you.

Comment: Thanks .. it helps...
On a pure design point of view , which is best practice , flowing hover or expanding the window ?

Comment: I would expand the window. using jQuery it will expand smoothly